# Memory leak in JSON serialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, memory-leaks, libraries

I have created a C# application and I have used JSON serialization. Currently the app is consuming too much working set memory. Could it be because of the NewtonSoft JSON library I have used? I also have used BouncyCastle library. Can it also create memory leaks? Please advice.

Comment: What do you mean "Currently the app is consuming too much working set memory"? Are you getting `OutOfMemoryException`s? If not that is the expected behaviour of any modern memory managed environment.

Comment: Yes I am getting out of memory exceptions. I want to know the part that JSON serialization plays in it. And if BouncyCastle and NewtonSoft also contributed to this

Comment: We might need to see some serialization code if you want a better answer.

Comment: The code is very complicated that I have to go through several classes.Could you tell me if those two libraries I have mentioned could be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `DataContractJsonSerializer` or `JavaScriptSerializer` instead of JSON.net? they are build-in in C# and MAY cause less problem than external libraries.

Details:
[DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

[JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try out Ants Memory Profiler. Memory management makes it difficult generally to locate memory usage.

However from my experience, `Newtonsoft.Json` doesn't have much in the way of potental memory leaks.

I haven't used BouncyCastle myself, so I can't tell you how well it works with memory. Given the nature of crypto, I would expect there are some parts that are unmanaged/native. Ensure that all `IDisposable` are Disposed on ALL code paths (I suggest using `using`, to ensure that happens even in the exceptional cases).

However, generally speaking, I would point the finger at my own code before well used community created libraries.